# Translating a sentence into a predicate formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Problem 3.40. (a) Translate the following sentence into a predicate formula:

There is a student who has e-mailed at most n other people in the class,
besides possibly himself.

The domain of discourse should be the set of students in the class; in addition, the only predicates that you may use are

- equality,
- E.x; y/, meaning that “x has sent e-mail to y.”

(b) Explain how you would use your predicate formula (or some variant of it) to
express the following two sentences.

1. There is a student who has emailed at least n other people in the class, besides possibly himself.
2. There is a student who has emailed exactly n other people in the class, besides possibly himself.

Comment: Do you know *quantifiers* ? Like e.g. $\exists x$

Comment: How are you asked to mange the "n" ? Do you know ["numerical" quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#univ) ? if not, Try with the simple cases : $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: How we have to read "besides possibly himself" ? That we have to exclude himself from counting, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Solution to part (a):
$
\exists s \Big((\forall u ^\neg E(s, u) ) \land \big( \exists x\exists y (x\ne y \land y \ne s \land x \ne s) \land (E(s, x) \lor E(s,y)) \land \forall z ((z \ne x \lor z\ne y \lor  z \ne s) \implies ^\neg E(s,z))\big) \Big)
$

- $(\forall u ^\neg E(s, u) )$ stands for the case that s does not send any one an email.
- $ E(s, x) \lor E(s,y)$ stands for  2 people
- $\forall z ((z \ne x \lor z\ne y \lor  z \ne s) \implies ^\neg E(s,z))$ stands for at most 2 people

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sir, may you check whether this solution is correct?